# How to make canvas responsive according to the div parent width

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design

So I am new to jQuery, I have been looking through the API that we can resize elements by using the resize() event handler, get the parent() div of a particular element and setting the attributes by using the attr() method.

I have tried the following code and when I output to console everything seems to be as expected (width changes according to the parent of the canvas elemt ). But when i resize the window, the canvas disappears:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var width = $('#line_chart_price').parent().width();
  $('#line_chart_price').attr('width', width);
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe try change $('#line_chart_price').attr('width', width); to $('#line_chart_price').attr('width', $width); or $('#line_chart_price').attr('width', +width);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redraw the canvas context on resize.

**JS**

```
var can = document.querySelector('canvas');
canCtx = can.getContext('2d');
canCtx.fillRect(50, 25, 50, 100); // a basic rect. you could set this to the width of the parent off the bat if you want.

$(window).resize(function () {
  width = $(can).parent().width();
  can.width = width;
  canCtx.fillRect(50, 25, width, 100);
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ejeqir/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example that reflects, Responsiveness of canvas as per the dimension of the parent element.

```
function outputsize() {
  console.log(textbox.clientWidth)
 myCanvas.width = textbox.clientWidth;
}
outputsize()

new ResizeObserver(outputsize).observe(textbox);
```

For HTML Structure please refer attached bin.
[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/cezezalefo/1/edit?html,js,console,output)